# Kotlin: Function-param implementation in a body of a caller

Tags: kotlin, function-parameter

```
fun lazyProperty(initializer: () -> Int): Int {                
  val result: Lazy<Int> = lazy(initializer)
  return result.value                   
}                

fun main(args: Array<String>) {                
  //    1.
  val bar: Int = lazyProperty({ 1 + 1 })
  //    2.
  val foo: Int = lazyProperty() {
    42
  }

  println("bar $bar, foo: $foo")
}
```

I recently stumbled over the syntax of calling a function in Kotlin and I just don't get it:
the fist option is clear - it's a lambda, but the second one looks not like a usual syntax of calling a function with the required parameter. The brackets where normally params should be placed are empty and instead the function-parameter comes in the body of the caller! How is it possible and what for is it needed?

Answer (score 3):

This is another valid way of passing a lambda. According to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html):

> In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter to a function is a function, and you're passing a lambda expression as the corresponding argument, you can specify it outside of parentheses:

```
lock (lock) {
    sharedResource.operation()
}
```

You can choose whichever approach you prefer.

Comment: Also note that if a function has only a single functional parameter, the parentheses can be omitted: `lazyProperty { 42 }`

Answer (score 1):

This is just convention. If the last param of a function is a function, you can pass the lambda outside the parentheses. In your case you have the following options:

```
val bar: Int = lazyProperty({ 1 + 1 })
val bar: Int = lazyProperty() { 1 + 1 }
val bar: Int = lazyProperty { 1 + 1 }
```

All three options are the same.

---

If your function would have a second parameter (at first position), than the calls could look like this:

```
fun lazyProperty(x: Int, initializer: () -> Int): Int {...}

val bar: Int = lazyProperty(7, { 1 + 1 })
val bar: Int = lazyProperty(7) { 1 + 1 }
```

---

If your function would have a second parameter (at second position), than the calls could look like this:

```
fun lazyProperty(initializer: () -> Int, x: Int): Int {...}

val bar: Int = lazyProperty({ 1 + 1 }, 7)
```

So always try to keep the Lambda at the last position of your function.